# Creating Data table from tabular report using Groovy

Tags: php, html, dictionary, groovy, html-table

I've been lumbered with the job of converting a list report into tabular data, and for various reasons the only programmatic tool I have is groovy (i.e. no shell commands, no C, no perl). The data comes pre-summarised, in five columns,

Grouping (e.g. company), Sub-grouping (e.g. Quarter), sub total, sub-group total, grand total (with the summary data tacked onto the first row of each group) :

```
Big Co.\t2009 Q4\t29\t88\t308
\t2010 Q1\t38\t\t          
\t2010 Q4\t21\t\t          
Gargantua Inc.\t2009 Q4\t33\t139       
\t2010 Q1\t31\t\t          
\t2010 Q2\t36\t\t          
\t2010 Q3\t39\t\t          
Mediocre Ltd.\t2009 Q4\t39\t81     
\t2010 Q4\t42\t\t
```

And the output needs to be something like:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Group</th><th>2009 Q4</th><th>2010 Q1</th><th>2010 Q2</th><th>2010 Q3</th><th>2010 Q4</th><th>Subtotal</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Big Co</th><td>29</td><td>38</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>38</td><th>308</th></tr>      
    <tr><th>Gargantua Inc</th><td>29</td><td>31</td><td>36</td><td>39</td><td>&nbsp;</td><th>139</th></tr>
    <tr><th>Gargantua Inc</th><td>39</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>42</td><th>81</th></tr>
    <tr><th>&nbsp;</th><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><th>308</th></tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to be able run some loops over the data; stick things into an associative array of associative arrays, building a complete key list as I go; then loop again to produce the output. I've taken a look at groovy, and the Map syntax has my completely thrown.

Can anyone point me to some clearer examples of groovy Map iterations, so that I can at least get a toe in the water with this?

Any help gratefully received.

(In case anyone thinks this is just a fishing trip, I've kludged together a PHP version that does the trick - essentially I need to be able to translate this into groovy... )

```
<?php
$rows           = explode("\n", $data);
$group          = "";
$subgroup       = "";
$table          = array();
$totals         = array();
$subgroup_names = array();
$group_names    = array();
foreach($rows as $key => $row) { 
  $rowData = explode("\t", $row);
  if($rowData[0]) {
    $group = $rowData[0];
    $group_names[$rowData[0]] = true;  
  }
  if($rowData[1]) {
    $subgroup = $rowData[1];
    $subgroup_names[$rowData[1]] = true;
  }
  $table[$group][$subgroup]['jobcount'] = $rowData[2];
  if($rowData[3]) $totals[$group]['jobcount'] = $rowData[3];
  if($rowData[4]) $totals['grandtotal'] = $rowData[4];
}
$group_names    = array_keys($group_names);
asort($group_names);
$subgroup_names = array_keys($subgroup_names);
asort($subgroup_names);  

$result = array();
$result['header'] = "<th>&nbsp;</th>"; 
foreach ($subgroup_names as $subgroup) {
  $result['header'] .= "<th>$subgroup</th>"; 
}
$result['header'] .= "<th>Subtotals</th>"; 

foreach ($group_names as $group) {
  $result[$group] = "<th>$group</th>";
  foreach ($subgroup_names as $subgroup) {
    $value = isset($table[$group][$subgroup]['jobcount'])?
      $table[$group][$subgroup]['jobcount']:
      '&nbsp;';
    $result[$group] .= "<td>".$value."</td>"; 
  }
  $result[$group] .= "<th>".$totals[$group]['jobcount']."</th>";
}

$result['footer'] = "";
foreach ($subgroup_names as $subgroup) {
  $result['footer'] .= "<th>&nbsp;</th>"; 
}
$result['footer'] .= "<th>Total</th>"; 
$result['footer'] .= "<th>".$totals['grandtotal']."</th>"; 

echo "<table><tr>".join($result, "</tr>\n<tr>")."</tr></table>";

?>
```

Comment: Is that how your data file is?  Exactly like the first formatted thing you pasted in?  Ie: `Big Co.` data is spread over 3 lines? And whitespace before the text on each line?

Comment: yup. :-( That's exactly how it is.... with the summary data for each group on the first line of the group, and the summary data for the whole set on the first line of the file. No, really. :-(

Comment: Actually, the white space may be me. But there's a tab for lines that are within the current group, e.g. lines 2,3,5,6,7, and 9 in the example data above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got this together...  It's maybe not the prettiest -- but then neither is the input format ;-)

```
String txt = '''Big Co.\t2009 Q4\t29\t88\t308
    \t2010 Q1\t38\t\t          
    \t2010 Q4\t21\t\t          
    Gargantua Inc.\t2009 Q4\t33\t139       
    \t2010 Q1\t31\t\t          
    \t2010 Q2\t36\t\t          
    \t2010 Q3\t39\t\t          
    Mediocre Ltd.\t2009 Q4\t39\t81     
    \t2010 Q4\t42\t\t'''

// Parse the text
def summary = txt.split( '\n' ).inject( [] ) { list, row ->
  def split = row.split( '\t' ).collect { it.trim() }
  while( split.size() < 5 ) split << ''
  if( split[ 0 ] ) {
    list << [ group:split[ 0 ], grouptotal:split[ 3 ], grandtotal:split[ 4 ], subtotals:[:] ]
  }
  list[ -1 ].subtotals << [ (split[ 1 ]):split[ 2 ] ]
  list
}

// Get a sorted set of all available quarters
def allQuarters = summary.subtotals*.keySet().flatten() as TreeSet

// Then build our html output
def writer = new StringWriter()
def builder = new groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder( writer )
builder.table() {
  // Header row
  tr {
    th "group"
    allQuarters.each { q ->
      th q
    }
    th "summary"
  }
  // Row for each group
  summary.each { group ->
    tr {
      td group.group
      allQuarters.each { q ->
        def v = group.subtotals."$q"
        if( v )
          td v
        else
          td { mkp.yieldUnescaped '&nbsp;' }
      }
      td group.grouptotal
    }
  }
  // Footer row
  tr {
    td { mkp.yieldUnescaped '&nbsp;' }
    allQuarters.each { q ->
      td { mkp.yieldUnescaped '&nbsp;' }
    }
    td summary.grandtotal.find { it } // Get the first non-empty grandtotal
  }
}
println writer.toString()
```

Comment: Tim - thanks - it looks great, and quite an advert for groovy ;-) However, one slight problem - seems to throw an error

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.LinkedHashMap.leftShift() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: {["2009 Q4":"29"]}

Comment: What version of Groovy are you running? I think leftshift on map was added in version 1.7.2

Comment: If you are on an old version and can't upgrade, then that line can be changed from `list[ -1 ].subtotals << [ (split[ 1 ]):split[ 2 ] ]` to `list[ -1 ].subtotals."${split[ 1 ]}" = split[ 2 ]`

Comment: Old version ? On this job nothing would surprise me ;-) Do I need to run some sort of import to get the java.util.TreeSet ?

Comment: Shouldn't do...  `java.util` should be imported by default http://groovy.codehaus.org/Differences+from+Java  Is it still giving you errors?  Post them here if so, and we'll fix them :-)

Comment: seems to be some sort of issue with casting the arrayList to a TreeSet... probably my version number. Will see if I can figure out an update to a newer version. Thanks for all your help Tim.

Comment: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '[2009 Q4, 2010 Q1, 2010 Q4, 2009 Q4, 2010 Q1, 2010 Q2, 2010 Q3, 2009 Q4, 2010 Q4]' with class 'java.util.ArrayList' to class 'java.util.TreeSet' was the latest

Comment: try changing `def allQuarters = summary.subtotals*.keySet().flatten() as TreeSet` to `def allQuarters = new TreeSet( summary.subtotals*.keySet().flatten() )` Honest, I did run the code before posting it here ;-)  It must be an old version of groovy making me look bad ;-)  What does `groovy -version` get you?

Comment: heh heh - how old would it need to be to get an exception on `groovy -version` ?

Comment: I'm not running groovy from the command line, but from within an environment to which I can pass groovy scripts to evaluate - how would I get at the version within a groovy script?

Comment: tried, `println org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getVersion()` but get nothing back... I _think_ that this machine may require a full defenestration. :-(

Comment: Tim - please don't waste any more time on this - I need to get on to the enivronment suppliers and find out why the basics are missing. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, good luck with it!  Hope someone manages to blow the cobwebs off the server for you ;-)